# Asp.net Mvc2 Data Annotations Validation (Client Side works, Server side Doesnt??)

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I'm using an entity model with metadata annotations.  My controller method looks like this...

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateModel(model);
            repo.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

If I enable client side validation in the view I'll get the error per the Attributes from the metadata class.  If I take clientside validation out, error gets thrown from saving to the DB rather than return the view with an Error Summary.

This is the top portion of my view....

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
```

I've tried running without debugging (ctrl + f5) in debug and release mode as well as setting breakpoints and Debugging (f5) but it just seems weird to get Client side validation without server side validation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateModel populates the model from form collection, routing parameters, etc. and does validation on the server side.  You need to check ModelState.IsValid **after** updating.  The usual pattern is...

```
if (!TryUpdateModel(model))
{
  // Validation Failed...
  return View(model);
}

// Validation Passed...
```

Note that TryUpdateModel catches exceptions and returns false if they're raised.  If they aren't, then it simple returns ModelState.IsValid.